# c++ deep copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char *s;
    int size;
public:
    String(const char *str = NULL); // constructor
    String& operator=(String &c){
        size = strlen(c.s);
        s = new char[size+1];
        strcpy(s, c.s);
    }
    ~String() { delete [] s; }// destructor
    void print() { cout << s << endl; }
    void change(const char *); // Function to change
};

String::String(const char *str)
{
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

void String::change(const char *str)
{
    delete [] s;
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

int main()
{
    String str1("learnc++");
    String str2 = str1;

    str1.print(); // what is printed ?
    str2.print();

    str2.change("learnjava");

    str1.print(); // what is printed now ?
    str2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

it can be compiled, and the result is:

```
learnc++ 
learnc++ 
learnjava 
learnjava
```

in addition to that,there is:

```
*** Error in `./code': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000f7f010 ***
```

BTY, if I delete "delete [] s;" in String::change,the result just becomes:

```
learnc++
learnc++
learnc++
learnjava
```

and no error appers, and why ?
the code is from geek foe feeks, I have changes some strings, and the code can be run in its IDE, but in my ubuntu 14.04, it cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is not following the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) because it is missing a proper copy constructor.

`String str2 = str1;` is just syntax sugar for `String str2(str1);`, so it uses the copy constructor, not your `operator=` (which has a memory leak, BTW).

Since you did not provide a copy constructor, the compiler provided one for you, but it does not make a deep copy of the `char*` data. It just copies the pointer itself, which causes the behaviors you are seeing.

A proper implementation would look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char *s;
    int size;
public:
    String(const char *str = NULL);
    String(const String &src);
    ~String();
    String& operator=(const String &rhs);
    void print() const;
};

String::String(const char *str)
{
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

String::String(const String &src)
{
    size = src.size;
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, src.s);
}

String::~String()
{
    delete [] s;
} 

void String::print() const
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

String& String::operator=(const String &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        String tmp(rhs);
        swap(s, tmp.s);
        swap(size, tmp.size);
    }
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    String str1("learnc++");
    String str2 = str1;

    str1.print();
    str2.print();

    //str2.change("learnjava");
    str2 = "learnjava";

    str1.print();
    str2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use this implementation instead, which follows the Rule of Five by adding move semantics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char *s;
    int size;
public:
    String(const char *str = nullptr);
    String(const String &src);
    String(String &&src);
    ~String();
    String& operator=(String rhs);
    void print() const;
};

String::String(const char *str)
{
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

String::String(const String &src)
{
    size = src.size;
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, src.s);
}

String::String(String &&src)
{
    size = src.size;
    s = src.s;
    src.s = nullptr;
    src.size = 0;
}

String::~String()
{
    delete [] s;
} 

void String::print() const
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

String& String::operator=(String rhs)
{
    swap(s, rhs.s);
    swap(size, rhs.size);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I didn't follow the rule, but after delete the user-defined copy-constructor, the error just appears, and thy is that?

Comment: @Jean do you mean you explicitly `delete` the copy constructor (`String(const String&) = delete`)? What error do you get exactly? If you `delete` the copy constructor then statements like `String str2 = str1;` (and `String str2(str1);`) can't compile anymore. Also, possibly related: [Default move constructor/assignment and deleted copy constructor/assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276413/)

Comment: just as the essay says, there exist "*** Error in `./code': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000f7f010 ***". Well , I can compile it in ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Add a copy constructor.

```
String(const String& c){
    size = strlen(c.s);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, c.s);
}
```