# C++ copy constructor: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have a class called `classA`, something like this:

```
class classA {
    private:        
        char* data; 
    public:
        classA(const classA&) = delete;
        ~classA();      
    };

~classA()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
```

In another class, let's call it `classB`, I have as a member a shared pointer to `classA`:

```
class classB
    {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<classA> ptrA;
    public: 
        classB(std::shared_ptr<classA>);
    };

classB(std::shared_ptr<classA> sp) : ptrA(sp)
    {}
```

This is how I instantiate my `classB`:

```
classA ca;
classB cb(std::make_shared<classA>(ca));
```

This gives me the following error:

> attempting to reference a deleted function

Obviously, I am trying to reference the copy constructor, which I defined as `deleted` (there is a reason for this, objects of this class shouldn't be copied). But I am confused as to why the copy constructor is called since I am passing a shared pointer, and how to avoid this.

Comment: how do you suspect the shared pointer is constructed?

Comment: Note that if you did `std::make_shared<classA>(std::move(ca))`, you'd still have a problem, see [Default move constructor/assignment and deleted copy constructor/assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276413/default-move-constructor-assignment-and-deleted-copy-constructor-assignment)

Comment: You should show actual code, your code cannot have that issue.

Comment: `make_shared` is trying to construct a `classA` from another `classA` (`ca`). What are you trying to do? Are you hoping for the `shared_ptr` to take ownership of `ca`?

Comment: @Tas you are wrong, `ca` is not an instance of `classA`

Comment: @Slava While it's true that `classA ca();` forward declares a function called `ca` that returns a `classA`, I think that we all know what the OP really did mean. Sure, they didn't post actual code, but it's still clear enough

Comment: Very good point though Slava, even after all these years most vexing parse still gets me evey. single. time. That said Justin is right also, I was just _assuming_ OP was making a proper `classA` otherwise I'm not sure how they'd come across this error (likely they'd have had a different one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the copy constructor trying to make the shared pointer.

```
std::make_shared<classA>(ca)
                         ^^ constructs the classA using these parameters
```

You can call `make_shared<classA>()` to create a shared pointer to a default constructed `classA`. Or chose another constructor.

Comment: If I had a constructor with parameters, let's say `classA(int n)`, how would I "choose" this constructor over the default one when creating the shared pointer?

Comment: Simple pass the desired constructor parameters directly to `std::make_shared()`, eg: `std::make_shared<classA>(12345)`.  Just like you did when passing `ca` to std::make_shared()` to call the copy constructor.

Comment: you would pass it to `make_shared` like `std::make_shared<classA>(someInt)`

Comment: I tried `auto x = make_shared<classA>(some_integer_value)`, and then `classB cb(x);`, but that gives me another error: classA (classA &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<classA >' to 'const classA &'

Comment: The error "*cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<classA >' to 'const classA &'*" means that `classB`'s constructor is expecting a `const classA &` as input, not a `std::shared_ptr<classA>`. Change `classB` to take a `std::shared_ptr<classA>` (so the `classA` can't be destroyed if `x` goes out of scope while `classB` is still using the `classA`), or else call `std::shared_ptr::operator*`, eg: `classB cb(*x);` and make sure `x` doesn't go out of scope before `cb`

Comment: consider making another question because that doesn't seem to match what you've posted above

Answer (score 4):

This example can be simplified quite a bit.

```
#include <memory>

class classA {
 public:
  classA(const classA&) = delete;
  classA() = default;
};


int main() {
  classA ca; // note, no ()
  auto sp = std::make_shared<classA>(ca); // problem.
  auto sp2 = std::make_shared<classA>();  // this does what you want
}
```

You are passing `ca` as an argument to `std::make_shared`, which constructs a `classA` by calling `classA::classA` with whatever arguments that you passed to `make_shared`.

This might be more obvious if you consider how a `make_shared` might be implemented.

```
template <typename Cls, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<Cls> MakeShared(Args&&... args) {
                                     //this is where the copying happens
  return std::shared_ptr<Cls>{new Cls{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
}

int main() {
  classA ca;
  auto sp = MakeShared<classA>(ca);
  auto sp2 = MakeShared<classA>();
}
```

You pass `ca` to `MakeShared`, which then calls `new Cls(...)` where the `...` is whatever you passed to `MakeShared`, in this case, another `classA` object.

If the above is too dense (maybe you aren't used to `forward` or variadic templates), then consider this simplified version of `MakeShared` which does the same thing for your problem case

```
template <typename Cls, typename Arg>
std::shared_ptr<Cls> MakeShared(const Arg& arg) {
                      // copy here ----+
                      //               v
  return std::shared_ptr<Cls>{new Cls{arg}};
}

int main() {
  classA ca;
  auto sp = MakeShared<classA>(ca);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!