# std::async monitoring thread age

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

I'm getting requests through a (thread-safe) queue. Each request than needs to be handled in a separate thread. There is a chance that the function (which is actually calling a Java-program via `_popen` and polling its output) takes a very long time. From the main thread I need a mechanism to indicate that situation (basically, measuring thread-running-time).

In my example I'm trying to 'enrich' `std::future` with some time information. The sample runs seamlessly, but I'm uncertain if this is the correct way. Also, even if it is the 'correct' way, I'm having trouble writing a copy-constructor and a assignment operator for `CFutureTest`, which I would like to control myself.

Here is a very simple demo that mimics what I'm trying to achieve:

```cpp
typedef std::future<int> FutureResultInt;

int ThreadFunc() {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  const int iRand = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(2000, 6000)(mt);
  std::cout << "ThreadFunc waiting for [" << iRand << "] ms ... " << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(iRand));
  std::cout << "ThreadFunc [" << iRand << "] done" << std::endl;
  return iRand;
}

class CFutureTest {
 public:
  CFutureTest() = delete;
  CFutureTest(FutureResultInt&& fr)
      : m_start(std::chrono::system_clock::now()), m_result() {
    m_result = std::move(fr);
  };

  int GetAge() const {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
               std::chrono::system_clock::now() - m_start)
        .count();
  }

  // private:
  FutureResultInt m_result;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_start;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<CFutureTest> futures;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    futures.push_back(std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, ThreadFunc)));
  while (futures.size() > 0) {
    for (std::vector<CFutureTest>::iterator it = futures.begin();
         it != futures.end(); ++it) {
      CFutureTest& future = *it;
      const std::future_status stat =
          future.m_result.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
      switch (stat) {
        case std::future_status::timeout:
          if (future.GetAge() > 4000) {
            std::cout << "Thread has exceeded the time limit" << std::endl;
          }
          continue;
        case std::future_status::deferred:
          std::cout << "std::future_status::deferred" << std::endl;
          continue;
      }
      const int iResult = future.m_result.get();
      std::cout << "future returned [" << iResult << "] (removing!)"
                << std::endl;
      futures.erase(it);
      if (futures.size() < 1) break;
      it = futures.begin();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A sidenote—you don't need to move from `std::async` return value, since it is an rvalue already. You can also initialize `m_result` member variable directly in constructor initializer list by `m_result(std::move(fr))`, which would generally be more efficient. Anyway, copy constructor/assignment for `CFutureTest` makes no sense, since the `m_result` member variable is not copyable.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your comment. How does vector internally handles `CFutureTest` if copy ctor/assignment oper is not available? Plus, if I add `CFutureTest(const CFutureTest& src ) = delete;` the compiler claims `attempting to reference a deleted function` (which kinda proofs that the copy-ctor is needed and used).

Comment: For `push_back`ing rvalues into `std::vector`, you just need a move constructor, which is in some cases generated by a compiler automatically for you. Such in a case of your original code. However, if you `delete` copy constructor, then you effectively prevent such generation of move constructor (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37276413/580083) for details). You can then generate move constructor by `CFutureTest(CFutureTest&&) = default;`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Besides your first note ('you don't need to move from std::async return value, since it is an rvalue already') - would you say that the general thought in my example is 'ok'?

Comment: Now, I'm afraid that I don't have time to investigate your whole code in details. However, note that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate site for code reviews.

Comment: I'll post the code there, thanks for the hint. And thank you for your time!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mikhail Except this is an example demo looking for validation, not real code looking for a review.

Comment: @Mast I don't understand what kind of response the author could expect except for stylistic review, or functionality checking. The functionality is fine, as he already notes. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/203856/52915)